# Kerberos and applicationhost.config

Tags: best-practices, iis, kerberos

One of our WebApplications is using Kerberos. Our devloper has said that we need to edit the application.config and change:

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="false">
```

to

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="true" useAppPoolCredentials="true">
```

Under the correct web application. I have a few questions regaring this.

1. Does this change need to be made on every server in our farm?
2. Is it best practice to manaullt edit the config file or should you do it another way?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part, yes you will need to do it on every web front end.

For the second part, it seems to be common practice, I don't know if it's *best* practice. It's a workaround for a limitation of SP2010 on Windows Server 2008 but there seems to be no ill-effects (or perhaps even some performance increase with it).

Note: There seems to be a (very recent) [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502606.aspx) talking more or less about this.